# subclassing QIODevice for QAudioDecoder

Tags: c++, qt, audio

Qt 5.7

According to the documentation, `QAudioDecoder` does not support streaming media. But is accepts either a filename or a `QIODevice` as source. Came the "bright idea": let's subclass `QIODevice` to create streaming media support.

But I always get an error:

> Unable to start decoding process. Stream contains no data.

I have checked and double checked and debugged. Can't figure out what can be the problem.

I'm only testing it, so the code below is by no means final.

header:

```
class InputBuffer : public QIODevice
{

public:

    InputBuffer(QString fileName);
    ~InputBuffer();

    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);
    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);

    bool   isSequential();
    qint64 bytesAvailable();
    qint64 size();


private:

    char*  bufferRef;
    qint64 length;
    qint64 position;

};
```

implementation:

```
#include "inputbuffer.h"

InputBuffer::InputBuffer(QString fileName)
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo(fileName);

    length   = fileInfo.size();
    position = 0;

    bufferRef = (char*)malloc(length);

    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    file.read(bufferRef, length);
    file.close();

    emit readyRead();
}


InputBuffer::~InputBuffer()
{
    free(bufferRef);
}


qint64 InputBuffer::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    if (position >= length) {
        return -1;
    }

    qint64 readSize = qMin(maxlen, length - position);

    memcpy(data, bufferRef + position, readSize);
    position += readSize;

    return readSize;
}


qint64 InputBuffer::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    return -1;
}


bool InputBuffer::isSequential()
{
    return true;
}


qint64 InputBuffer::bytesAvailable()
{
    return length - position;
}


qint64 InputBuffer::size()
{
    return length;
}
```

usage:

```
inputBufferRef = new InputBuffer("/home/pp/Zenék/Test.mp3");
inputBufferRef->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

audioDecoderRef = new QAudioDecoder();

audioDecoderRef->setAudioFormat(audioFormat);
audioDecoderRef->setSourceDevice(inputBufferRef);

connect(audioDecoderRef, SIGNAL(bufferReady()),               this, SLOT(decoderBufferReady()));
connect(audioDecoderRef, SIGNAL(finished()),                  this, SLOT(decoderFinished()));
connect(audioDecoderRef, SIGNAL(error(QAudioDecoder::Error)), this, SLOT(decoderError(QAudioDecoder::Error)));

audioDecoderRef->start();
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do you subclass QIODevice? You can use ready sublasses of QIODevice. For example, in your case you can use QFIle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your `isSequential()`, `bytesAvailable()`, nor `size()` methods override the respective method in `QIODevice`, because the signatures don't match. They are all missing a `const` qualifier. Using the C++11 `override` keyword when overriding virtual methods helps.

Comment: Feeling embarrassed... how could I overlook this? Thank you, it works perfectly now.

Comment: For the sake of those who want to implement this or something similar. After playing with it further, I found that: 1. don't have to override `size`, which is great for streaming, but 2. do have to override `pos` otherwise the decoder will be out of sync and the sound will stall or will be too fast.